# How do I get the r_basicprofile permission on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

**The problem:**
We need the public profile url or `vanityName` of the users authenticating with LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 on our website for a social feature. But apparently LinkedIn does not give out permissions for that OAuth scope by default and you need to request it.

**What we've found so far:**
The only "application" process we've found for that is through the Marketing Developer Platform which has a whole bunch of other stuff while we only need this one permission. So our request for that one got rejected.

**What we're doing right now:**
The `r_liteprofile` we're using right now does not include the profile url of the user. Contacting LinkedIn support didn't help. They just told us to ask any developer portal related questions on StackOverflow with the #linkedin tag.

Is there any other way to get permissions for this OAuth scope apart from applying for the marketing developer platform? If there is no other way, what's the criteria to get access the marketing developer platform? LinkedIn support has been very unhelpful with this entire matter.

Answer (score 4):

Our understanding is that all permissions besides `w_member_social` are obtained by adding the "Marketing Developer Platform"

Comment: yeah, seems like it, and to get it you need to submit a form that asks all sorts of questions related to your business and how you plan to use their api. smells very microsofty

Comment: In 2023, inside the products overview it is now termed "Advertising API".

Answer (score -1):

Now you need to apply here to get access to the r_basicprofile scope which provides the VanityName

[image]